# How Load xmlHttpRequest resources inline/sequentially with ES6 Promises & Generators?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, generator, ecmascript-6, yield

How would I create a "data = xhrLoad(url)" function which is async inside but w/o .then or callback "hell"?  I want xhrLoad to do Promise/Generator magic, but only return when the data is available.

Example:

```
data = initMyProgram(); // may call data = xhrLoad(url)
<use data here>
<more inline code here>
```

I realize Promises are wonderful, and .then/.catch are sophisticated .. but I want inline, sequential code .. not then-able code fragments that may not even be needed if the data is available w/o external resources.

Ex: In webgl programming, shaders can be in `<scripts>`, in external files, in es6 modules, in es6 template strings, etc. I want to manage this by having xhr requests, if needed, magically be completed before initMyProgram returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to do in ES6, it's not necessarily very convenient. But there are a couple of [blog posts](http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/no-promises.html) about it, it should be quite straightforward to follow them.

There is a proposal for [`async/await`](https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait) for ES7. [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/#es7-experimental-) already supports.

Note that `async/await` is just syntactic sugar for handling promises. Functions declared as async always return a promise, thus at the top level you still have to use the promise API. `await` can only be used inside `async` functions, but anything that returns a promise can be awaited.

[Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20foo()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20resolve(42)%2C%203000)%3B%0A%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20bar()%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20answer%20%3D%20await%20foo()%3B%0A%20%20console.log(answer)%3B%0A%20%20return%20answer%20*%202%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Abar().then(result%20%3D%3E%20console.log(result))%3B%0A):

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(42), 3000);
 });
}

async function bar() {
  let answer = await foo();
  console.log(answer);
  return answer * 2;
}

bar().then(result => console.log(result));
```

Keep in mind that this is an experimental feature and the way it works may change over time.

Comment: Yup, there is a cute stunt to do this via generators.  Generators are the only functions designed to pause at each "yield". If the yield returns a promise, then the yield call can .then the promise with the result .. and when calling next, include the result: it.next(image) say.  This has the magic result of placing the result in the previous yield's result. Mind numbing.  But the result is you replace "await" with yield and you've got a poor man's async function.